# How to run executable file in Apple Script

Tags: bash, applescript, filemaker

I'm trying to run a executable file using applescript in FileMaker.

I've been trying...

```
do shell script "./firstscript"
```

This results in the error "sh: ./firstscript: No such file or directory"

---

If I type './firstscript' directly in bash the file is properly being executed.

Any ideas on how I should be pointing to my executable file inside the apple script?

Comment: You probably have the wrong working directory - use a full path instead.

Comment: The full path did the trick.  Thanks :)

Comment: OK, great - I've made that an answer now in case anyone else has a similar problem in the future.

Comment: BTW the "." is a  reference to the "working directory". Example: type "open ." in a terminal window and it opens the working directory with "Finder". Just for fun you could try that and see what folder opens :) that would be the working directory of your script.

Comment: Your working directory is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have the wrong working directory - use a full path instead, e.g.

```
do shell script "/path/to/firstscript"
```